# LDAP Authentication in Liferay does not work

Tags: ldap, liferay, liferay-6

I configured liferay to use LDAP (AD) for authentication. The import works, and user can login.

When I activate the "Required" checkbox on the LDAP tab in Configuration Panel the login fails and I get following lines in the liferay log:

```
15:22:26,766 DEBUG [http-bio-80-exec-6][LDAPSettingsUtil:52] Search filter before transformation (sAMAccountName=@screenname@)
15:22:26,766 DEBUG [http-bio-80-exec-6][LDAPSettingsUtil:67] Search filter after transformation (sAMAccountName=@screenname@)
```

Shouldn't the `@screenname@` in the second line be replaced by the username in the login form?

Configuration:

`How do users authenticate` is set to `By Screen Name`

`Authentication Search Filter` is set to `(sAMAccountName=@screenname@)`

Liferay Version : Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check following configuration.

```
Authentication Search Filter - (sAMAccountName=@screen_name@)
Import search filter - (objectClass=person)
```

[image]

Also check if authentication is set to screenname in Portal Settings - Authentication - General
[image]

Comment: I am so blind. Thank you.